# How to download multiple files in Zip - Velo by Wix

Tags: velo

I need help to download multiple files in Zip - Velo by Wix. And I added the following code on my Wix website but it is not working. I need immediate help from someone. Thank you in advance. [JSZip, axios, file-saver]

```
import JSZip from 'jszip';
import axios from 'axios';
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';

$w.onReady(function () {

    const zip = new JSZip();

    const fileArr = [{
            name: "file1.png",
            url: "https://logos-download.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Wix_com_logo_black.png",
        },
        {
            name: "file2.png",
            url: "https://logos-download.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Wix_com_logo_black.png",
        },
        {
            name: "file3.png",
            url: "https://logos-download.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Wix_com_logo_black.png",
        },
    ];

    const download = (item) => {
        return axios.get(item.url, { responseType: "blob" }).then((res) => {
            zip.file(item.name, res.data);
        });
    };

    const downloadAll = () => {
        const arrOfFiles = fileArr.map((item) => download(item));
        Promise.all(arrOfFiles)
            .then(() => {
                zip.generateAsync({ type: "blob" }).then(function (blob) {
                    saveAs(blob, "hello.zip");
                });
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    };

    $w('#downloadBtn').onClick(() => {
        downloadAll();
    });
});
```